# Run ODE's from multiple MATLAB files simultaneously

Tags: matlab, function, ode

I have ode's created in two functions present in two .m files. I am trying to combine the ode's from both the functions and run it simultaneously.

The followings are the functions,

Main function :**runtoy** - Uses ODE45 twice to solve the ode's present in two functions named **toy** and **yot**, individually.

```
function runtoy()
%% toy
Nnodes = 5;
vc = 50;
vz0 = [280 100 150 180 110];
vz = vz0(2:4)';
tspan = [0 2];
[tz,dvzdt] = ode45(@(t,y) toy(t,y,vc), tspan,vz)
plot(tz,dvzdt)

hold all
plot(tz,vc,'*')
%% yot

[tc,dvcdt] = ode45(@(t,z) yot(t,z,vz(2)), tspan,vc)
hold all
plot(tc,dvcdt)
hold all
plot(tc,vz(2),'o')
legend({'toy-vz1','toy-vz2','toy-vz3','toy-vc','yot-vc','yot-vz2'})

%%EDIT

init = [vz' vc]; 
Combined = ode45(@(t,v) combined_ODEs(t,v), tspan ,init')
end
```

First set of ODE's present in function **toy**

```
function dvz = toy(t,y,vc)
vz = y;
Matrix = [-2 0 0;1 -3 1;0 -4 1];
Connect = [0;conn(vz(1),vc);0]; 
dvz = Matrix*vz -Connect;
end
```

ODE present in function **yot**

```
function dvc=yot(t,z,vz)
dvc = conn(vz,z);
end
```

The function **conn** called within function **yot** and **toy**

```
function c= conn(vz,vc)
c = vz - vc/3;
end
```

Could someone give suggestions on how to solve the ode's present in both functions simultaneously? I can have these functions in a single file. But, I am using this as a test case to implement for my real system.

EDIT : Trial of method suggested in the comment

```
function dV = combined_ODEs(t,V)
vz = V(1:3);
vc = V(4);
dV(1:3,1) = toy(t,vz,vc);
dV(4,1) = yot(t,vc,vz(2)); % not sure what z is here??
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As the two ODEs are couple, my suggestion would be to write (yet) another function that references the two (or more) functions that define the ODEs and solve that instead, i.e. something like that:

```
function dV = combined_ODEs(t,V)
vz = V(1);
vc = V(2);
dV(1) = toy(t,vz,vc);
dV(2) = yot(t,z,vz); % not sure what z is here??
end
```

Comment: Could you please tell how the ode45 should be called after combining? z is vc.Also, can we directly assign toy(t,vz,vc) to dV(1)? The function toy has 3 differential equations (dvz  is a matrix). The vector vz with initial conditions for solving dvz in toy has 3 values.Could you please clarify?

Comment: I created the new function `Combined_ODEs`.Could you please have a look?

Comment: That looks good. Have you tried it? You need to call it with a vector of 4 initial conditions and it should work. Make sure all the functions are on your MATLAB path.